# docker compose to delay container build and start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have couple of container running in sequence.

i am using depends on to make sure the next one only starts after current one running.

i realize one of container has some cron job to be finished , 
so the next container has the proper data to be imported....

in this case, i cannot just rely on depends on parameter.

how do i delay the next container to starts? say wait for 5 minutes.

sample docker compose:

```
  test1:
    networks:
      - test
    image: test1
    ports:
      - "8115:8115"
    container_name: test1

  test2:
    networks:
      - test
    image: test2
    depends_on:
      - test1
    ports:
      - "8160:8160"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use entrypoint script, something like this (need to install netcat):

```
until nc -w 1 -z test1 8115; do
  >&2 echo "Service is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
sleep 2
>&2 echo "Service is up - executing command"
```

And execute it by [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) instruction in service (in docker-compose file) or in the Dockerfile (CMD directive).

Comment: i am not looking for method to check service available or not. but a timer predefine. the service available then next service up isn't working now. because service available, then coupld of cron jobs still need to be completed then next service is safe to be up.

Answer (score 0):

I added this in the `Dockerfile` (since it was just for a quick test):

```
CMD sleep 60 && node server.js
```

A 60 seconds sleep did the trick, since the node.js part was executing before a database dump init script could finish executing fully.